# Cannot set background of jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do a background image in bootstrap jumbotron.  I cannot get the image to fit into its div accordingly.  The div is spilling out of its container.

here is my html

```
<div class="jumbotron">

    <div class="jumboView left jumbotronContent"> 

        <h3>The equipment you want AND THE FINANCING TO MAKE IT HAPPEN </h3>

    </div> 

    <div class="jumboView right jumbotronImage"> 
        <h1>Images coming soon...</h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the background into the content div.  I will next be putting a banner over it.

```
Here is my css 



.jumboView {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.jumbotronContent {
  position: relative;
  background: #000 url('../images/Capital Machinery Corp Logo.png') center  center;
  background-size: 100%;
  /*width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
```

The images is supposed to take up the left side.  However, it is covering the entire div.  When I comment it out my divs are seperate left to right.

Comment: tried it in jsfiddle, seems to be doing what it's supposed to. http://jsfiddle.net/kv9ctkdz/

Comment: Yes it does, what you are trying.

Comment: I am sorry.  My server was not restarting.